# How to filter LINQ to SQL result by xref table property

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table which has codes and is linked with a table of employees by an `xref`. I want to filter the results based on the linked table's ID property. I can't seem to get the predicate correct, what am I doing incorrectly?

```
    public static IQueryable<TblProjCd> ByEmployeeId(this IQueryable<TblProjCd> qry, int employeeId)
    {
        //Return the filtered IQueryable object
        return from q in qry
               where q.TblEmployee.ToList().FindAll(p => p.EmployeeId == employeeId)
               select q;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you by chance mean:

```
public static IQueryable<TblProjCd> ByEmployeeId(this IQueryable<TblProjCd> qry, int employeeId)
{
    //Return the filtered IQueryable object
    return from q in qry
           where q.TblEmployee.Any(p => p.EmployeeId == employeeId)
           select q;
}
```